# How to prevent blank page when switch page in progress for Angular 4

Tags: angular, router

my app.component.ts
template:

```
<commonLoading [hidden]="loading"></commonLoading>
<my-header></my-header>
<router-outlet class="router-outlet"></router-outlet>
```

The commonLoading component is a spinner with a transparent background.

I have 2 page (component A and component B).
when I switch the page form component A to component B. The html page will show a blank page.

It seem the progress is
page A -> blank -> page B

My expection is when I switch to component B from component A. The html will switch to component B only when it is ready.
page A -> page B

I have tried to pause in debugger when the blank show.
the HTML DOM like that

```
<app-root>
  <commonLoading></commonLoading>
  <my-header></my-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <componentA>
    <!--bindings={}-->
  </componentA>
</app-root>
```

and the height of above HTML is not cover the whole screen, may be 30 view height only. so the screen show a blank screen. I doubt if it can be solved.

Comment: Please, provide more code. How do your pages A and B look like? How do you switch between then and when?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main component (Default: `AppComponent`) Add following code.

**MyAppComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouteConfigLoadStart, RouteConfigLoadEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class MyAppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof RouteConfigLoadStart) {
        document.getElementById('pageLoader').style.display = 'block';
      } else if (event instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd) {
        document.getElementById('pageLoader').style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In your Index.html above app-root tag add whatever page loader you want to add like following.

**Index.html**

```
<!-- Page Loader -->
<div id="pageLoader" style="display: none">
    <!-- Add image loader here -->
    <img src="assets/page-loader.gif">
</div>

<app-root></app-root>
```

Here `RouteConfigLoadStart` will give that routing has started and will show loader and when routing has finished `RouteConfigLoadEnd` will trigger and loader will be hidden again.

Comment: I tried your approach but it can't help. Although I can place the loader when loading, the last page will disappear. I expect the last page and loader will exist until the next page exist in the screen.

I doubt if too many code in OnInit of the component page so the blank page exist.